# JavaScript waiting for load page and click

Tags: javascript

I need to type movie title in the search input and click on the "Search" button,
then I need to wait for the page load and click on it
I need to do it in Console of Browser
Here is my code

```
document.getElementById('story').value='Troy';
document.querySelector('body > div.wrapper > div.header > div.header44 > div.search_panel > span > form > button').click();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click();
} );
```

If I do these steps separately, everything works.
But I need to do it all at once (by one script)
Here is the last action, waiting for the page load and clicking on it

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click();
} );
```

I think this last action is triggered ahead of time
how to write this code correctly?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414766/9636400

Comment: it didnt help also "document.addEventListener("load", () => {" last action is triggered ahead of time, could you help me modify my code by using MutationObserver?

Comment: The question is impossible to answer based on the code shown.  MutationObserver will not do anything.

Comment: Yogi, sir what else can I show you?