# How to assign a variable to await which is inside void method in Cefsharp C#

Tags: c#, async-await, cefsharp

This is what I have:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string jsScript1 = "some java script code";
   await Task.WhenAll(chrome.WaitForLoadAsync(), chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript1));

   string jsScript2 = "some java script code";
   await Task.WhenAll(chrome.WaitForLoadAsync(), chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript2));

   string jsScript3 = "some java script code";
   await Task.WhenAll(chrome.WaitForLoadAsync(), chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript3));
}
```

How to assign a variable to await if i want to return a result and process it?

What I would like to accomplish

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
    
   string jsScript4 = "some java script code";
   var task = await Task.WhenAll(chrome.WaitForLoadAsync(), 
   chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript4));
   task.ContinueWith(x =>
   {
     if (!x.IsFaulted)
     {
       var response = x.Result;
        if (response.Success == true)
        {
          var final = (List<object>)response.Result;
          foreach (var el in final)
          {
            textHtml.Text += el.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
          }
        }
     }
   }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

But Im getting the error "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable"

How can i solve this problem?

---

Solution by using Thread.Sleep

```
string jsScript1 = "some java script code";
            await Task.WhenAll(chrome.WaitForLoadAsync(), chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript1));

            string jsScript2 = "some java script code";
            await Task.WhenAll(chrome.WaitForLoadAsync(), chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript2));

            string jsScript3 = "some java script code";
            await Task.WhenAll(chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript3));


//Its important to delete "chrome.WaitForLoadAsync()" look above!
            Thread.Sleep(2000); 
            string jsScript4 = "some java script code";
            var navigationTask = chrome.WaitForLoadAsync();
            var evaluateTask = chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript4);
            await Task.WhenAll(navigationTask, evaluateTask, evaluateTask.ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (!x.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var response = x.Result;
                    if (response.Success == true)
                    {
                        var final = (List<object>)response.Result;
                        foreach (var el in final)
                        {
                            textHtml.Text += el.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()));
```

How to rewrite this code without using Thread.Sleep?
Im using `chrome.WaitForLoadAsync()` aka "navigation task" but this does not work at line with `jsScript4`, maybe because in `jsScript3` clicks on link with load links, there is no navigation there, but loads links on current page, maybe i need class like `chrome.WaitForLoadAsync()` for load links/load classes

Comment: Did you try `Task task = await Task.WhenAll(......)` ?

Comment: Why do you use `ContinueWith`?

Comment: @Guru Stron, how can i use? could you show me?

Comment: It would be better if you could write what you want to achieve using words like "I need to assign whatever `EvaluateScriptaAsync` returns to a button text" rather than showing the code of desired result. So you have two tasks, elaborate please on what do you want to do with them when they complete?

Comment: I always work in the JavaScript side and, from JavaScript, I send results to C# using Bound Object. In this way, you can run all your scripts and do that scripts send theirs results to your C# application. In C#, you can run your 4th script after receive the three results/notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply store the task as a variable and access it's Result property after the await Task.WhenAll call.

```
var navigationTask = browser.WaitForLoadAsync();
var evaluateTask = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);

await Task.WhenAll(navigationTask, evaluateTask);

var response = evaluateTask.Result;
```

Comment: please take a look my New addition #3, why its does not work...

Comment: it's so strange. when im debugging my code it's work perfectly. but when i start my program by F5 its does not work...

Comment: I found the solution by using Thread.Sleep, please read above

Comment: This correctly answers the original question. What you are describing now is a different problem, you should remove those edits and ask a new question as your original question has been answered.

Comment: Also use await Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep as you are likely sleeping your UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

result of `await Task.WhenAll(...)` is void, so you should await *something else* :)

```
   string jsScript4 = "some java script code";

   var valueTask = chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript4);

   var waitTask = Task.WhenAll(
       chrome.WaitForLoadAsync(),
       valueTask);

   await waitTask.ContinueWith(waitTask =>
   {
     if (!waitTask.IsFaulted)
     {
       var response = valueTask.Result;
        if (response.Success == true)
        {
          var final = (List<object>)response.Result;
          foreach (var el in final)
          {
            textHtml.Text += el.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
          }
        }
     }
   }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: please take a look, i added image above

Comment: Resutl of `await Task.WhenAll` is not always `void`, it depends on the method called `WhenAll<TResult>` vs `WhenAll`

Comment: ah, didn't noticed you use result
Result of which task you want to use — WaitForLoadAsync or EvaluateScriptAsync ?

Comment: @E.Shcherbo I guess Rigorich got it mixed up with `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: WhenAll will have return value only if all waited tasks have it
I suppose in question there is void and smth returned, so WhenAll returns void

Comment: @Rigorich, both tasks are important, WaitForLoadAsync - required for javascript navigation

Comment: I modified my answer. Amaitland's solution below is simplier, by the way, but do not considering IsFaulted

Comment: @Rigorich, please take a look, i added another image above

Comment: @Rigorich, it's so strange. when im debugging my code it's work perfectly. but when i start my program by F5 its does not work...

Comment: @Rigorich, I found the solution by using Thread.Sleep, please read above

Comment: There is no needs in `ContinueWith` if `await` is used.

Comment: @Rigorich There is no need to check for IsFaulted when using await as the exception will be propagated to the calling method.